# Как поместить переменные с данными в одно сообщение?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Необходимо получить данные из таблиц MySQL, а после собрать их и поместить в одно сообщение.
Пример моего неправильного цикла:

```py
tickets = row  # список кортежей из БД
buttons_dict = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(tickets)}
print(buttons_dict)

for x in buttons_dict.values():
    await query.message.answer(x)
```

Также очень желательно, я бы хотел узнать, как сделать так, чтобы данные не просто выводились в не самом лучшем виде в сообщение, а чтобы можно было также поместить в отдельное сообщение, дополнительно приукрасив его.
Например (это все одно сообщение)

```
Билет один:

Пин-код - #данные
Имя - #данные

Билет два:

Пин-код - #данные
Имя - #данные

и т.д
```

Comment: Что у вас в `tickets`?

Comment: А вообще вы должны в цикле сформулировать строку а уже после него отправить её.

Comment: В tickets - {0: ('Роррр', 275714, 'Meet&Greet', 0, 0, '0', '21-01-2023 15:17', 'System'), 1: ('авп', 342891, 'Meet&Greet', 0, 0, '0', '21-01-2023 15:14', 'System')

Comment: Где:
первое - имя
второе - пин
третье - тип тарифа

и т.д

Comment: А это точно tickets, а не buttons_dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает при условии что `tickets` это то что вы скинули в комментарии.

> tictets = {0: ('Роррр', 275714, 'Meet&Greet', 0, 0, '0', '21-01-2023 15:17', 'System'), 1: ('авп', 342891, 'Meet&Greet', 0, 0, '0', '21-01-2023 15:14', 'System')}

```
result = ""
for num, value in tickets.items():
    result += f"Билет №{num+1}\n"
    result += f"Пин-код: {value[1]}\nИмя: {value[0]}\n\n"

await query.message.answer(result)
```

Comment: Невероятно тебя благодарю. Огромное спасибо... наконец +1 к знанию цикла. А про buttons_dict - это так, взял строку у себя из кода